# Displaying MaxDate value by default Bootstrap Date time picker

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I am using bootstrap date time picker and setting maxdate value, so what's happening is I am getting the max date value selected by default.

```
 $(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear() - 10;
    var date2 = new Date(year + '/' + month + '/' + day);
    $('.dob').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        minDate:'1/1/1950',
        maxDate: date2,

    });
});
```

I have tried givng

> defaultDate:''

still the issue is same, any suggestions.